# How to show DatePicker & TimePicker controls over the Popop that contains them?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-toolkit

I'm trying to create a popup with Windows Phone Toolkit DatePicker & TimePicker, with the following XAML:

```
<Popup x:Name="MyPopup">

    <Border BorderThickness="2" Margin="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">

        <StackPanel>

            <toolkit:DatePicker Name="datePicker" />
            <toolkit:TimePicker Name="timePicker"/>

        </StackPanel>

    </Border>
</Popup>
```

This works, but every time I click either of them, they are rendered under the popup, e.g.

[image]

I can't figure out any way to hide the Popup while displaying the DatePicker or TimePicker.

I've tried setting the Z-Index of the controls to be greater than the Popup, as follows:

```
void timePicker_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.SetZIndex(timePicker, Canvas.GetZIndex(MyPopup) + 1);
}
```

I've also tried hiding the Popup with

```
void timePicker_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Popup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

but this closes the popup and the TimePicker/DatePicker.

Is there any way to view the DatePicker/TimePicker controls on top of the Popup control?

Comment: Do you think something like this? http://sdrv.ms/1bVpamc

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. Please supply this (or at least the salient parts of it) as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sample project.](http://sdrv.ms/1bVpamc)

XAML

```
    <Border
        Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"
        BorderThickness="2"
        Margin="10"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">

        <StackPanel>

            <toolkit:DatePicker
                Tap="DatePickerTap" />

            <toolkit:TimePicker
                Tap="DatePickerTap" />

        </StackPanel>

    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Code behind

```
private bool pickerIsOpen = false;

// constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += this.MainPageLoaded;
}

// page loaded
private void MainPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.pickerIsOpen)
    {
        this.MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
        this.pickerIsOpen = false;
    }
}

// date/time picker tap
private void DatePickerTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    this.pickerIsOpen = true;
}
```