# How to display Date in Dropdown box

Tags: windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

below is the standard Date Picker

```
<DatePicker MonthFormat="{}{month.full}"
            DayFormat="{}{day.integer} ({dayofweek.abbreviated})"
            YearFormat="{}{year.full}"/>
```

I have the question as below:

1. How to display a list of dates (long dates) in the dropdown box or combo box if possible?
   Example:

   Mon 14 Jul
    Tue 15 Jul
    Wed 16 Jul
2. The Date Picker 
   a) How to fix it to current year
   b) How to fix it to current Month

Answer (score 0):

For the `DatePicker` you could go with the control from the `Windows Phone Toolkit` from [Codeplex](https://www.codeplex.com/).

A reference for this would be:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/windows-phone-7-datepicker-control/

[How to show DatePicker & TimePicker controls over the Popop that contains them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223247/)

Hope it helps!